# Scanf-reading variables which have to meet ceratin specifications

Tags: c++, c, variable-assignment, scanf

I have to solve an exercise which at first glance seemed really simple to me. However, I am not so sure how to solve it. Given the fact that variables `a` and `b` have certain admissable values, should I verify whether they are in the correct range after reading them? And regarding variable `b`, in the examples it is given in scientific notation, so should I read it using the `e` specifier? And last but not least, the assignment supression of `',`' is done using `"%*[,]"`?

> Write a set of statements to read from the standard input three variables `a`, `b` and `c`, where the variables have the following types:
>
> `a` – unsigned short integer, `b` – float, `c` – string of at most 31 characters
>
> The input values are separated by one comma. The first variable is given as an octal number. The admissible values for a and b are as follows:
>
> ```
> -4331 < a <= 28731
> -1035 < b < 9749273
> ```
>
> Suitable error messages should be given if the values are not within the allowed range or in the wrong format. Sample input:
>
> ```
> 12745, -1.e-3, Is this a good one? 
>
> 0xEE04F, 21e75, Maybe this one... 
>
> 70073, 21e+6, Or this one. Could this string be too long to put into allocated area?
> ```

Comment: There's really no way of verifying values unless you actually read them. You can verify that the input you `scanf` is of the correct type by checking the return value from `scanf`.

Comment: If you have access to a Linux box, the manual page for `scanf` is quite comprehensive.  (If you don't, you should be able to find it with a quick Google search.)  You also need to understand the division of labor between `scanf` and code you will need to write after the call to `scanf` to validate your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP: should I verify whether they are in the correct range after reading them?
A: Yes.  The scanning will check gross range error.  Then code checks local range.

OP: read it using the `e` specifier?
A: `a`, `e`, `f`, `g` are all equivalent in `scanf()` family.  So use what seems appropriate: `e` is good.

OP: the assignment suppression of ',' is done using `"%*[,]"`
A: Almost: One could use "`%*1[,]"`, but `","` is sufficient.

Use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` and then check range.

```
char buf[1000];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
  handle_EOF_or_IOError();
}
short Number;
float x;
char s[31+1];
if (3 != sscanf(buf, "%ho,%e, %31[^\n]", &Number, &x, s)) {
  handle_ParseError();
}
short NumberTooSmall = -4331;
short NumberMax = 28731
float xTooSmall = -1035.0f;
float xTooBig = 9749273.0f;
if ((Number <= NumberTooSmall) || (Number > NumberMax) ||
    (x <= xTooSmall) || (x >= xTooBig)) {
  handle_RangeError();
}
```

Note: there is a subtle issue on when the parsed string begin in "12745, -1.e-3, Is this a good one?", etc.  OP says that `,` is the seperator.  This implies the string starts with `" Is this ..."`.  I think the OP wants to skip leading spaces and get `"Is this ..."`.

Assuming [IEEE binary32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary32) for `float`, `9749273.0` needs 24 bits to represent exactly.  Since this format has 23+1 bits of precision for normal numbers, all is well.  Care should be observed with range testing of floating point values.